# Gson Retrofit Json API returns Webpage on Error

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I am using an API the returns a Json object `{ "results": 1, "data": [...]}` on success and a webpage "`<DOCTYPE HTML> <HTML>.... </HTML>`" on error. How can I handle this? I am using Retrofit 2 and Gson on Android in Java. I am also using two custom deserializers to handle string returned instead of object when a data item errors out.

Comment: is your json response working fine in browser or postman?

Comment: does both the responses(success, error) hits the onResponse method?, if it does not hit the onresponse method you may have implemented the custom deserializers incorrectly

Comment: I think you miss understand. This issue isn't that the request errors out. The issue is that I must support request errors. When I send a proper request, I get a proper response. When I send a request the contains cities that the api doesn't have information on, it response with an html page informing the user of the lack of information in the api's database.

Comment: No, the json response hits onResponse. This is how it should be as gson fails to parse the html response. The custom deserilizer I wrote does not handle this issue by design. It is for handling differences in data types returned in the json response. I can't seem to find a way to get the complete response in a deserializer when the response isn't json.

Comment: @user693336 have you tried using `ResponseBody` instead of `String` to parse html response? So, in your custom deserializer specify object for success response and `ResponseBody` for error response(html response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use the OkHttp3 ResponseBody for your call, and based on the type of the response either parse the Json with Gson or display an error ?

For instance you can create a function that determines if a string is a gson like this:

```
public static boolean isJson(String Json) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
        gson.fromJson(Json, Object.class);
        return true;
    } catch (com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then do your retrofit call like this:

```
Call<ResponseBody> res = yourService.yourmethod();
res.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            try {
                String resString = response.body().string(); 
                if (isJson(resString)) {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    YourModel responseObject = gson.fromJson(resString, YourModel.class);
                    // do something with the object

                } else { // this is not a Json so most likely your html response

                    // Do something else, like display an error
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

If you need to parse the html to display what is returned, you can also use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org), here it would be something like `Document document = Jsoup.parse(resString);`, then do what you need with the result.

You also have the option of using a WebView and directly display the html response in it, with `webView.loadData(resString, "text/html", "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

According to the response code, you can handle it but it should take care by your backend. Backend developer should give proper error message along with response code.

Comment: The backend is not mine. I can't changed it. This is a commercial api I am using. The html response is the way the provider designed it.

Answer (score 0):

in case the API returns something else than `HTTP 200 OK` on error, one can differ:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<SomeModel> call, @NonNull Response<SomeModel> response) {
    switch(response.code()) {

        case 200: {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                ...
            }
            break;
        }

        default: {
            if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                String content = response.errorBody().string();
                ...
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The API does return 200 with the html error page. So the request cannot be filtered by response code. After all, html is a legitimate response... So the response code is correctly 200.

Comment: @user693336 it's absurd to return `200` on error - as well as to return HTML for a JSON API. eg. `404` on a website may commonly have HTML content, too. one barely can rationalize `200` as "correct response code" while the result was not `OK` and no JSON is being sent.

Comment: if the API does not send a JSON response with proper HTTP headers, this is not a client-side problem.

Comment: Handling the error is a client side issue. When an app asks the API for info and that info is not returned, the app needs to notify the user as to why.

Comment: The opinion of whether the implementation is right or wrong wont help me git my project completed. However, a 200 is understandable as the html page is valid html. Returning html from a json API is indeed questionable. But again, that is how this API was implemented and I have to work with it.